# String array comparing with user string gives access error

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am trying to build a program which will take in a `list` of login details (usernames and passwords) from a file and allow you the option to enter a username and password which are compared with the approved logins and a result is given. In my `strcmp` I am receiving `access violation error 0xC0000005`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

FILE *fptr;
void main();
void openFile();
void closeFile();
char approvedUsrnames[3][6];
char approvedPassword[3][6];


void main()
{
    char userPassword[6], usrname[6], inputChar, fileString[6];
    int i;
    openFile();

    int numofLogins= 3;


    if (fptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nReading file with scanf\n");
        while (!feof(fptr))
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                fgets(approvedUsrnames[i], 6, fptr);
                fgets(approvedPassword[i], 6, fptr);
            }

        }
        closeFile();
    }


    printf("Enter User name: ");
    scanf("%s",usrname);
    printf("Enter the password <any 6 characters>: ");

    for (i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        inputChar = _getch();
        userPassword[i] = inputChar;
        inputChar = '*';
        printf("%c", inputChar);
    }//obfuscate the input to the user

    /*If you want to know what you have entered as password, to be removed*/
    printf("\nYour password is %s:", userPassword);


    for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\Username is good %s\n", approvedUsrnames[i]);

        if (strcmp(approvedUsrnames[i], usrname  == 0)){
            printf("\Username is good\n");
            if (strcmp(userPassword, approvedPassword[i]) == 0) {
                printf("\nPassword is good\n");
            }//end nested if
            else {
                printf("\nPassword is not match\n");
            }
        }//end if
    }//end for

    _getch();

}
void openFile()
{
    fptr = fopen("approvedLogins.dat", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file ! \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Login file read successfully ! \n");
    }
}
void closeFile()
{
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: `userPassword` is not NUL terminated.

Comment: @kaylum can you explain what you mean by this and how I would resolve it ?

Comment: You are using `userPassword` as a string (in `strcmp` for example). Strings in C must have a `\0` character as the last byte in the array. Your `userPassword` has 6 bytes of non-NUL data and hence is not a valid C string. One fix is to allocate an extra space for the NUL and explicitly intialise the variable: `char userPassword[7]=""`;`

Comment: Adding a char and initialising the string produces the same error on the strcmp

Comment: Well, you have a typo: `strcmp(approvedUsrnames[i], usrname  == 0)`. The `==0` is incorrectly within the `strcmp`.

Comment: Also, if the user types more than 5 non-whitespace characters in response to the request for user name, you will overwrite memory and possibly crash.

Answer (score 0):

@anthonygordon

1. It is very likely that the strings usrname and userPassword aren't being terminated with '\0' (null terminator) a) as the scanf() may attempt to fill in more chars than usrname can capture b) for loop has to iterate only 5 times so that userPassword[5] is to be explicitly set to '\0'. (If the expectation is to use 6 character long username and password, then change the length of array from 6 to 7 and make sure array[6] is filled with '\0') (Remember in 'C' array subscripts goes as 0..(arraysize-1))
2. Also, once the user name and password matches, break-out from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You picked specific lengths for your username and password character arrays. This means that you know the amount of characters you want to compare.

In such a case you do not need to add a '/0' to your character array. Simply use the strncmp() function and specify the number of characters to compare in the second parameter.

See:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncmp.htm

Just a tip: 
Test after every bit of code that you add. This way it is easy to know what code caused the problem. Only when you get really experienced (perhaps 4+ years of coding) can you be brave and write more code before testing.